# Getting list of location (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm new to Core Location, I want to know how to get the list of location like in iPhoto when we share photo to Facebook.

For example :

1. User type in "New York", and then click "Search"
2. The tableview will show a list of location with that name. It will also present the geotag information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Facebook does not have "Location", what it does have is "Place", kind of a 'check-in'.
But, we're not able to create the Place object programmatically, we're only able to lookup of a place based on the Latitude & longitude.

And fortunately, Apple already provided CLGeocoder to lookup for location and its Lat & Long, and from this I can supply Facebook's Place's Lat & long.